# $window.alert not working inside angular function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to popup an alert message from an angularJS function, but it's not working.

**Script**

```
app.controller("APIController", function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.saveSubs = function () {
    var sub = {
        UserName: $scope.username,
        Password: $scope.password
    };
    if ($scope.username === 'admin' && $scope.password === 'admin') {
        window.location.href = '/Home/HotelSearchRedirect';
    } else {
        $window.alert("User name or password wrong. please enter correct username or password.");
    }
};});
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Use `window` instead of `$window`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$window` needs to be injected.

```
app.controller("APIController", function ($scope, $http,$window) {
$scope.saveSubs = function () {
    var sub = {
        UserName: $scope.username,
        Password: $scope.password
    };
    if ($scope.username === 'admin' && $scope.password === 'admin') {
        window.location.href = '/Home/HotelSearchRedirect';
    } else {
        $window.alert("User name or password wrong. please enter correct username or password.");
    }
};});
```

Just replace this code.

Answer (score 4):

Only alert("User name or password wrong. please enter correct username or password.") will be suffice.

There is no need of window or $window.

Answer (score 2):

You should use **`window`** instead of **`$window`**,

```
  window.alert("User name or password wrong. please enter correct username or password.");
```

Comment: From the AngularJS documentation: "In AngularJS we always refer to it through the $window service, so it may be overridden, removed or mocked for testing." https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

Answer (score 1):

Inject `$window`.

```
app.controller("APIController", function ($window, $scope, $http) { 
   // Code
});
```